# Issue get email from facebook via android application

Tags: android, facebook, email

In my application, i have problem for getting mail,

My code,

```
private void getFbName() {
                mProgress.setMessage("Fetching data ...");
                mProgress.show();

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String name = "";
                        String email = "";
                        String firstname = "";
                        String lastname = "";
                        String gender = "";
                        int what = 1;

                        try {
                            String me = mFacebook.request("me");

                            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(me)
                                    .nextValue();
                            System.out.println(jsonObj);
                            name = jsonObj.getString("name");
                            email = jsonObj.getString("email");
                            firstname = jsonObj.getString("first_name");
                            lastname = jsonObj.getString("last_name");
                            gender = jsonObj.getString("gender");


                            what = 0;
                            name = name + "~" + email+"~"+firstname+"~"+lastname+"~"+gender;
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());

                        }

                        mFbHandler.sendMessage(mFbHandler.obtainMessage(what, name));
                    }
                }.start();
            }

            /** The m fb handler. */
            private Handler mFbHandler = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();

                    if (msg.what == 0) {
                        String username = (String) msg.obj;
                        username = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;

                        SessionStore.saveName(username, getApplicationContext());

                        String[] cre = username.toString().split("~");
                        if (cre != null) {
                            String fbname = cre[0];
                            String fbemail = cre[1];
                            String fbfirstname = cre[2];
                            String fblastname = cre[3];
                            String fbgender = cre[4];
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    fbname+fbemail+fbfirstname+fblastname+fbgender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Utilities.setUserRole("1");
                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    getBaseContext(),
                                    com.petapp.fragment.ItemListActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Connected to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
```

My json response

```
{"work":[{"employer":{"id":"108225245912126","name":"globas"}}],"hometown":{"id":"105868576120246","name":"Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu"},"location":{"id":"105868576120246","name":"Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu"},"locale":"en_US","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/peter.das.395","education":[{"type":"College","school":{"id":"115034085174725","name":"CSICE KETTI"}}],"updated_time":"2013-05-24T08:24:55+0000","id":"100005889543373","first_name":"Peter","timezone":5.5,"username":"peter.das.395","verified":true,"name":"Peter Das","last_name":"Das","gender":"male"}
```

My logcat says,

```
W/System.err(9081): org.json.JSONException: No value for email
W/System.err(9081):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
W/System.err(9081):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510) 
W/System.err(9081):     at com.petapp.demographic.LoginActivity$8.run(LoginActivity.java:263)
E/LoginActivity(9081): No value for email
```

but at the same time i am using different facebook credential i will get mail id 
i dont what is going here ?? pl help anyone....

Comment: way too much code to look through. isolate the issue and post only what is relevant.

Comment: Check if you are getting the result in [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail)? [Don't forget to select the App you are working on]